# Geopandas generate empty plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, coordinates, geopandas

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cZidf9taJ8&t=3671s) . Basically, I want to plot the image values from a raster formatted 40 band image in scope of the ground-observation data points (shapefile). But when I try to plot it gives me a blank sub-plots.

```
    #read points from shapefile
train_pts = gpd.read_file (training_points)
train_pts = train_pts[['class', 'classes' ,'CID', 'POINT_X','POINT_Y']] #attribute fields os shapefile
train_pts.index = range(len(train_pts))
coords = [(x,y) for x, y in zip(train_pts.POINT_X, train_pts.POINT_Y)] #create list of point coordinates

#sample each band of raster dataset at each point in the coordinate list
train_pts ['Raster Value'] = [x for x in dataset.sample(coords)] #all band values saved as a list in the Raster Value column
#Unpack the raster value column to separate column for each band 
train_pts[band_names] = pd.DataFrame(train_pts['Raster Value'].tolist(), index = train_pts.index)
train_pts = train_pts.drop(['Raster Value'], axis=1) #drop raster value column
#change the values for last three classes 
train_pts['CID'] = train_pts['CID'].replace([7,8,15],[5,6,7])
train_pts.to_csv('train_pts2.csv') #save as csv
train_pts.head (30) #see columns
```

the out for this code is this: [image: this]
And then I run this code to get the sub-plots with this code:

```
prof = train_pts.groupby (['classes']).mean ()
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (17,20))
band_n = [ 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8' ,'NDVI' ,'VH', 'VV']
n = 1
for ba in band_n:
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4,2,n)
    ax.title.set_text(ba)
    band_val = prof[prof.columns[prof.columns.to_series().str.contains(ba)]]
    for index, row in band_val.iterrows():
        color = cmap (index)
        ax.plot (row,color=color)
        ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis="both", tight=None)
    ax.set_xticklabels([str (x) for x in range(1, len(row)+1)])
    ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize='small', ncol=2, labels=class_names)
    n=n+1
```

The out is this: [image: this]

But instead this is the output that I wanted to get : [image]

I also double-check the projections of the raster and the point data, it's same.  What else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) creates line plots. When you loop through both rows and columns as you're doing, you end up with only a single point passed to each plot command, so you're plotting a bunch of lines with length 0.

I think you want [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), and to pass the full columns of `x`, `y`, and `c` as arguments. From the `plt.scatter` docs:

> **`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`***`(x, y, s=None, c=None, marker=None, cmap=None, norm=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None, *, edgecolors=None, plotnonfinite=False, data=None, **kwargs)`*
> A scatter plot of y vs. x with varying marker size and/or color.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **x, y :** ***float or array-like, shape (n, )***
> The data positions.
>
> ...
>
> **c :** ***array-like or list of colors or color, optional***
> The marker colors.

So, to plot all points in the raster, just plot once per column:

```py
for i, ba in enumerate(band_n):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4, 2, i +1)
    band_val = prof[prof.columns[prof.columns.str.contains(ba)]]

    # check to make sure you're matching exactly one column
    assert band_val.shape[1] == 1, (
        f"unexpected columns: {band_val.columns}"
    )

    ax.scatter(
        x=prof['POINT_X'],
        y=prof['POINT_Y'],
        c=band_val.iloc[:, 0],
    )
```

Depending on the size of your data and the point density, this may take a long time to render, and the points themselves may overlap. Instead, you may want to check out [`matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html), which can plot data on a regular grid.

That said, if your data is on a regular grid, you may want to check out [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html), which is set up well for working with gridded data. You'd need to make sure that your x and y values are indices of a regular, complete grid, e.g. every value of y is exactly repeated for every combination of x. But if that's the case, you could convert your dataframe to an xarray dataset with [`df.to_xarray`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xarray.html): `ds = prof.set_index(['POINT_X', 'POINT_Y']).to_xarray()` then plot with `ds[band_name].plot()`.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add the result that I wanted to get. Now I edited it. Isn't it possible to calculate the mean for each of the classes for each band with .groupby and .mean functions and plot it with pyplot.plot?

Comment: huh - I can't tell what you're actually plotting. what are the column names you want as your x, y, and line hues in the plots? it does look like you should be using multiple line plots, but not one per cell.